# Sylow $p$-subgroups and their relation with normalizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $P$ and $P'$ be Sylow $p$-subgroups of a finite group $G$. Prove that if $P'\subset N_G(P)$ then $P'=P$.

**Proof:** Since $P\vartriangleleft N_G(P)\leq G$ and it's easy to check that $P$ is also Sylow $p$-subgroup in $N_G(P)$. Because it's normal then the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N_G(P)$ is equal to one. By condition $P'\subset N_G(P)$ then $P'$ is also Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$. Hence $P'=P$.

I have spent a whole day in order to solve this easy problem. However, it became easy to me after solution. The key point is that the $P$ is also Sylow $p$-subgroup in $N_G(P)$.

Is my solution correct?

Thanks in advance for evaluation.

Comment: Looks fine to me...

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Yes well done, and you proved that since $P$ is (by definition of the normalizer) normal in its normalizer $N_G(P)$ and of course $P$ is Sylow in $N_G(P)$, it is the *unique* Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$.